# combing count and bin in python

Tags: python, pandas, bin

the questions I am working on is: Between which sale milestones (0-> 5, 5 -> 10, 10 -> 15, etc. up to 50) do we lose the largest number of sales reps?.

The df looks like this

```
    id      call_starttime  level
0   66547   7/28/2015 23:18 1
1   66272   8/10/2015 20:48 0
2   66547   8/20/2015 17:32 2
3   66272   8/31/2015 18:21 0
4   66272   8/31/2015 20:25 0
```

I can get the count of sales for each id, but I can't figure out how to apply the bins to this (be nice I am new to this)

this is how I am getting the counts

```
byNoconvo = df.groupby(["cc_user_id"]).count()["convo_starttime"].sort_values()
```

Comment: Is `id` the same as `cc_user_id` and `call_starttime` the same as `convo_starttime`? Also, what exactly are the "sale milestones"? Can you provide your expected outcome?

Comment: yes cc_user_id and call_starttime the same as convo_starttime. the expected outcome is something like  milestone     count
0-5 calls       30
5-10 calls      20
ect....
where the mlestone are the bins and increments of 5 up to 50 and count is the number of sales reps (ie unique ids)